# Format number to always show a fixed decimal point upto 4 decimal?

Tags: javascript

I have to format the number in such a way that it should show up to 4 decimal point so I tried using toFixed() but it fails in one of the cases i.e.

```
 var x = 13734801434463221200
 x = toFixed(4)
```

In that case it results in loose of precision and I also tried using **toLocaleString()** but that's also not working for me .Do we have some other way to do the stuff?

Comment: why parse a number? what result do you expect?

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry in my case its  a string

Comment: i have the same problem some of the solution i searched is usiing regex

Comment: we're talking about the language that says `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3` :D

Comment: `13734801434463221200` exceeds the [max safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER). If you want precision for those big numbers, you'll need to use a different type.

Comment: @andymccullough What makes you think JS is the only language that 'says' this?

Comment: Look into `BigInt` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Comment: do you have only integers or long floats as well? how do you get this value into javascript?

Comment: @KooiInc never said it was the only language ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andymccullough then what's the use of your comment? There may be enough in JS to mock about, but actually not [this floating point 'error'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPBjd-vb9eI)